# Receiving an error 'System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I know that the error message in the title indicates that the application that I'm running the XML code in doesn't seem to recognize it as XML. I've compared it to other coding I've used recently and cannot find the issue. One big difference, however, is that I'm using XSLT along with it, which may be the cause. I've included a snip of the XML & XSLT coding for reference.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <GLPayrollExportConfiguration>
          <definitions>
            <FileType Value="CSV"/>
            <FileName>
              <Value Value="GL_Summary_"/>
              <Value Value="paygroup_xref"/>
              <Value Value="_"/>
              <Value Value="payrun_payperiod_and_suffix"/>
              <Value Value="_"/>
              <Value Value="transaction_timestamp"/>
              <Value Value=".csv"/>
            </FileName>
            <Settings>
              <SplitMode Value="HOME_LOCATION_SPLIT"/>
              <ChartOfAccountXRefCode Value="GL"/>
              <RunOnPayRunCommit Value="True"/>
           </Settings>
            <Header>
              <Text Value="Posting Date,"/>
              <Text Value="Document Type,"/>
              <Text Value="Account Type,"/>
              <Text Value="Account No,"/>
              <Text Value="Fund No,"/>
              <Text Value="Dimension Speedkey Code,"/>
              <Text Value="Dimension 1,"/>
              <Text Value="Dimension 2,"/>
              <Text Value="Dimension 3,"/>
              <Text Value="Dimension 4,"/>
              <Text Value="Dimension 5,"/>
              <Text Value="Dimension 6,"/>
              <Text Value="Dimension 7,"/>
              <Text Value="Dimension 8,"/>
              <Text Value="External Document No,"/>
              <Text Value="Description,"/>
              <Text Value="Amount,"/>
            </Header>
            <Columns>
              <Column Name="PostingDate" DataType="datetime" Source="data" Value="payrun_pay_date" Sort="true"/>
              <Column Name="ColumnC" DataType="string" Source="mapping"/> 
              <Column Name="AccountNo" DataType="string" Source="data" Value="payrun_category_override_journal_number"/>
              <Column Name="FundNo" DataType="string" Value="UNREST"/>
              <Column Name="DimensionSpeedkeyCode" DataType="string" Source="mapping"/>
              <Column Name="Description" DataType="string" Source="mapping"/>
              <Column Name="Amount" DataType="number" Source="data" Value="payrun_amount" Function="sum" />
            </Columns>
          </definitions>
          <MappingDefinitions>
            <definition>
            <criteriaset> 
        <!-- EXCLUDE MEMO DEDUCTIONS AND TAXABLE BENEFITS / JOURNAL NUMBER CODED AS exclude, Exclude, or EXCLUDE  -->   
                <criteria item="payrun_category_override_journal_number" op="ne">EXCLUDE</criteria>
                <criteria item="payrun_category_override_journal_number" op="ne">Exclude</criteria>
                <criteria item="payrun_category_override_journal_number" op="ne">exclude</criteria>
        <!-- EXCLUDE RECORDS WITH with 0 VALUE -->
                <criteria item="payrun_amount" op="ne" opDataType="number">0</criteria>
            </criteriaset>
            <mapping>
                <mapto columnname="Col C">
                  <Value Value="&#x0009;"/><Value Value="PAYROLL"/>
                  <Value Value="payrun_pay_date"/>
                </mapto>
                <mapto columnname="Dimension Speedkey Code">
                  <Value Value="&#x0009;"/><Value Value="override_segment_charged_dynamic_org_level_onsitedepartment"/>
                  <Value Value="override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber"/>
                </mapto>        
                <mapto columnname="Description">
                  <Value Value="&#x0009;"/><Value Value="payrun_pay_date"/>
                  <Value Value=" "/><Value Value="payrun_category_name"/>
                </mapto>        
            </mapping>
            </definition>   
          </MappingDefinitions>
          <ColumnFormats>
            <ColumnFormat Name="PostingDate" Format="MM.dd.yy"/>
            <ColumnFormat Name="ColC" Format="YYYYMMDD"/>
            <ColumnFormat Name="AccountNo" WrapChar="&quot;"/>
            <ColumnFormat Name="DimensionSpeedkeyCode" WrapChar="&quot;"/>
            <ColumnFormat Name="Description" Format="mm.dd.yy" WrapChar="&quot;"/>
            <ColumnFormat Name="Amount" Format="{0:##.00}"/>
          </ColumnFormats>
         </GLPayrollExportConfiguration>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber=' '">
                    <xsl:value-of select="override_segment_charged_dynamic_org_level_onsitedepartment"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I tested it with `xsltproc` and it doesn't throw an error. But it just doesn't produce any output, either.

Comment: There is no whitespace allowed before the XML declaration, hard to tell whether in your input  XML sample that is just the indentation for the code sample or indeed the cause of the error message.

Comment: Martin, I don't have any whitespace before the XML declaration. I, too, am able to run the job without an error.  There is data in the db that I'm running the code against, but I don't get an output file and do see the error message in the job log referencing the error in the title field.  Weird.

Comment: Your downstream app may be producing the error message because your XSLT code doesn't produce anything.  And, therefore, is not well formed XML with a root node.

Comment: So is there code (e.g. Java, C#) written that performs the XSLT transformation? Some APIs, at least on the Microsoft platform, have two methods `load` and `loadXML` which people confuse and pass a URI or file name to the `loadXML` method which, however, expects the XML markup as a string. That could cause such an error message. Bluewood has a good hint as well to check.

Comment: I've updated the XSLT coding and think I have resolved all of the issues with the tags not being terminated properly. Still getting the same error, though.

Answer (score -1):

I can't repeat the error. However, it looks like your choose block tests will always fail and default to the `<xsl:otherwise>` block.

Your path for the `when` test is incorrect and will never select the attribute you want.
For a dirty solution to get it to succeed you can use:

`<xsl:when test="//Value[@Value = 'override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber'] = ''">`

`//` is generally a ham-fisted approach. In this case, `//Value` selects all `Value` nodes in the document.

`@Value` selects an attribute of a node, which is the only place I could find your occurrence of 'override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber'.

`[]` the square brackets in Xpath contain predicates -- or selection criteria.

`Value[@Value = 'override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber']` returns the `Value` node where the predicate is true.

note: I'm only using `//` as an example of how it will succeed. You should really find the correct pathing for your situation.